# How to place an image between bullet point and text in ul?

Tags: html, css

I want to place an image between the bullet point and the text in an unordered list, I have tried several ways but the last one closest to the point was this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="../2/question/img/zeplin.png" alt="zeplin" style="float: left;">
        <p>Zeplin</p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
        <img src="../2/question/img/dropbox.png" alt="dropbox" style="float: left;">
        <p>Dropbox</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**This is a photo of the goal:**

[image: and this is a photo of the goal]

How can I write this?

Answer (score 4):

```css
li img {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/103/2592/1936.jpg?hmac=aC1FT3vX9bCVMIT-KXjHLhP6vImAcsyGCH49vVkAjPQ"
        alt="zeplin" style="float: left;">
        <p>Zeplin</p>
    </li>
    <br>
    <li>
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1029/4887/2759.jpg?hmac=uMSExsgG8_PWwP9he9Y0LQ4bFDLlij7voa9lU9KMXDE" 
        alt="dropbox" style="float: left;">
        <p>Dropbox</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but how about being the text and the bullet point lower? they'r at the floor length in the photo

Answer (score 1):

Simply use list-style-image property in your unordered list and put the image url inside url method. Example:

```
ul {
      list-style-image: url('your_image.png');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
li img, p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlm3P.png"><p>Zeplin</p>
    <li><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgOJ5.png"><p>Dropbox</p>
    </ul>
```